# Как сгруппировать по дням dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть [dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ETDHjmlthS0cas-mVr72a7-HfiP2hyT_/view?usp=sharing) со столбцами:

1. НоменклатураКод( название),
2. КоличествоОборот(сколько продано единиц товара всего за указанный период)
3. СуммаОборот(всего продано по деньгам, то есть цена 1 единицы товара умножить на КоличествоОборот)
4. Период(дата, какой-то дань)

Как сделать dataframe, чтобы по дням можно было сгруппировать наименования товаров, то есть дата, НоменклатураКод(это название товара) Количество проданное за день этого товара(это сумма КоличествОборот за день), Общая цена(это сумма СуммаОборот за день)?

```
funcs = dict('КоличествоОборот' ="summ", 'СуммаОборот' ="summ")
art3 = art.resample('D').agg(funcs)
```

Не получается, надо уникально по каждой НоменклатураКод( название) : То есть Товар - дата - объем - общая цена. То есть по каждому товару посчитать сколько было за день объема с общей ценой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно

```
data = pd.read_csv('art.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=['Период'], dayfirst=True, index_col='Период', decimal=',')
groupDate = data.groupby(['Период','НоменклатураКод']).sum()
```

У вас проблема в том, что дробная часть в числе отделена запятой, а должна быть точкой.

Comment: Надо уникально по каждой НоменклатураКод( название)

Comment: Так не получается groupDate = data.groupby('Период', 'НоменклатураКод').sum()

Comment: Можно перечислить несколько полей для группировки. Добавил поле.

Comment: На счет точки так записалось в csv файл, у меня нормально с точкой на самом деле, спасибо, просто в другом проблема: нужно по уникальности товаров сгруппировать еще

Comment: Я добавил уникальность товаров